# sqlite query to find sum of a year by the given dates

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios6

I have written a query :   `SELECT YEAR(Date),SUM(replace(price, ',', '')) FROM example GROUP BY year(date);`         .I am trying to get sum of all price for that year but I am getting an error - no such function : year. Please guide me .I am a noob in db.Thanks again.

```
12/10/11        377,245.67
12/19/11        5,104,245.00
12/28/11        23,332.98
12/24/10        126,875.21
12/24/10        5,112,225.14
12/23/10        4,552.54
11/24/10        402.82
10/15/09        132,875.32
9/19/09     126,334,123.32
9/23/09     345,887.21
9/29/09     16,520.11
9/28/09     388,902.02
11/12/08        24,622.43
10/25/08        278,916.52
10/12/08        42.22
9/22/08     17,234.01
9/16/08     377,245.67
12/15/07        5,104,245.00
12/18/07        23,332.98
12/19/07        126,875.21
12/22/07        23,332.98
12/28/07        126,875.21
```

Format I am looking for:

```
Year(Date)               price
8           438483479.3
9           8774343479
10          5654389.34
11          5654354646
12          23434483479
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT strftime('%Y', Date),SUM(replace(price, ',', '')) FROM example GROUP BY strftime('%Y', Date);
```

Comment: I tried the query and it did not work as it was supposed to.I got sum of all price and strftime('%Y', Date) was blank.I wanted it to add all the dates in that year to add and show the total sum for that year and so on..for every date included in the table but its blank please help.

Comment: tell me what this query gives you SELECT strftime('%Y', Date) from example;

Comment: now try this and tell me what this query gives you SELECT strftime('%Y', date (Date)) from example;

Comment: I still get a blank field.I guess I need to specify the format of date column as in mm-dd-yy is the current format inserted in sqlite and I guess while retieving data I need to specify that and call the year function I guess.

Comment: lets do in different way try this SELECT substr(Date,7,2) from example;

Comment: I am getting the year for most of the fileds except few which have 3/3/4 or 5/6/5

Comment: I guess it would be great if I can get value after second '/' so regardless of the number after it eg: /05 /5 , I will still get 5 as the year value.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest this sintax:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y',Date), SUM(replace(price, ',', '')) FROM example GROUP BY strftime('%Y',Date);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried the query and it did not work as it was supposed to.I got sum of all price and strftime('%Y', Date) was blank.I wanted it to add all the dates in that year to add and show the total sum for that year and so on..for every date included in the table but its blank please help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function `year()` in sqlite. You must use function `strftime()` instead.

For example, to get year value of the field Date, you can use `strftime("%Y", Date)`.

Therefore, you must replace `year(Date)` in your query by `strftime("%Y", Date)`.

Comment: @Prasad Jadhav,@An Cong Tran  : I tried the query and it did not work as it was supposed to.I got sum of all price and strftime('%Y', Date) was blank.I wanted it to add all the dates in that year to add and show the total sum for that year and so on..for every date included in the table but its blank please help.

Comment: i guess the field Date is type String instead. Therefore, replace strftime("%Y", Date) by substr(Date, 7, 2). cheers.

Comment: Thanks An Cong Tran I formatted the date pattern before entering it into sqlite db then the above function works!! Standard sqlite db format yyyy-mm-dd.Thanks again.