# SQLite convert date

Tags: sqlite

I have a column of data type `TEXT`:

```
date
----
DD/MM/YYYY
```

but I want to convert all rows in the column to:

```
date
----
YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00
```

(Yes, 00:00:00 for all rows)

Is there any way to do it in SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

<s>Use [strftime](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).</s>

```
strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', date_str);
```

**EDIT:**
Yes, my first quess do not work. This one does, though:

```
SELECT 
date,
substr(date,7,4)||'-'||substr(date,4,2)||'-'||substr(date,1,2)||' 00:00:00' as text_repr,
datetime(substr(date,7,4)||'-'||substr(date,4,2)||'-'||substr(date,1,2)||' 00:00:00') as datetime_repr
FROM
t
```

Simply put - You have to parse it on Your own, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021609/change-date-format-in-sqlite) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428795/sqlite-convert-string-to-date)...

Comment: Thanks. I tried it using `SELECT date, strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', date) FROM t;` and it shows the old date `29/06/2007` in column ` and _NULL_ in column 2.