# How to change Text Date into Date data type in SQLite and change its display format

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a column that its contents are dates as text (For example, `"5/24/2023"`). There are more than 213000 records. How can I write a query to change the date to `"2023-05-24"` format?
I studied [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021609/change-date-format-in-sqlite) post but it couldn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Date` [data type in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Your dates are strings (`TEXT` data type) and you can use [string functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) to convert their format to the proper ISO format:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET date = SUBSTR(date, -4) || '-' ||
           printf('%02d', date + 0) || '-' ||
           printf('%02d', SUBSTR(date, INSTR(date, '/') + 1) + 0);
```

Change `date` to the name of your column.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/xC_y3l9i).